Bugs with udp-tcp connections and plot
I have this viewModel file ,when i hide my main plot and show a second one something happens like it freezes my main plot.I tried to restart my app but i have the same issue.
It will work only if i restart my device application from where i send the data.
The thing is that its still transmitting the data into my c# code because i can see it from my logs in both apps (device and c# applications),so my c# is receiving them but not plotting them.
Here is my code :
private async void InitializeRenderingLoop()
 {
  _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  await UpdatePlotAsync(IP, port);
 }


 private async Task UpdatePlotAsync(string ipAddress, int port)
 {
     using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
     {
         _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
         var token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
         udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
         udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("ipAddress"), port));

         while (!_isPaused && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
             if (_stopAll) break;
             try
             {
                 var result = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                 if (result.Buffer.Length == 0) continue;
                 var receivedData = result.Buffer;
                 string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedData);
                 var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlotValues>(message);
                 if (jsonData == null || jsonData.AUData == null)
                 {
                     Debug.Print("Failed to parse JSON or 'AUData' is missing.");
                     return;
                 }
                 if (jsonData == null || jsonData.AUData == null)
                 {
                     Debug.Print("Failed to parse JSON or 'AUData' is missing.");
                     return;
                 }
                 double[] yData = jsonData.AUData;
                 if (yData == null || yData.Length == 0)
                 {
                     Debug.Print("yData is null or empty.");
                     return;
                 }

                 var pointData = GetWavelength(yData);
                 var series = (LineSeries)SpectralPlotModel.Series[0];
                 series.Points.Clear();
                 foreach (var point in pointData)
                 {
                     series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(point.X, point.Y));
                     //Debug.Print(pointData.ToString());
                 }
                 SpectralPlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Debug.Print($"Error receiving UDP packet: {ex.Message}");
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }

 public async void OnLockChanged()
 {
     LockButtonVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     GoBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
     IsSpectralPlotVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
     IsSpectralAEPlotVisible = Visibility.Visible;
     await AEHTTP.SendAEValues(wV, ScanWindow, IntesityThreshold);
     await UpdateAEPlotAsync(ipAddress, port);
 }
 public void OnGoBackChanged()
 {
     LockButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
     GoBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     IsSpectralPlotVisible = Visibility.Visible;
     IsSpectralAEPlotVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
     InitializeRenderingLoop();
 }

UpdateAEPlotAsync its just a second Plot with a different port and OnLockChanged with OnGoBackChanged are my buttons.
Also for the dispose if it helps :
    public class PlotViewModel : ObservableObject, IDisposable

And a Dispose method :
        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.Print("Entered the Disposed Method");
                _stopAll = true;

                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();

                SpectralPlotModel.Annotations.Clear();
                SpectralPlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print($"Error in Dispose: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }


Debugging becomes so much easier if you separate code for A) network, B) serialization, C) plotting. That should let you test each component individually.

Also, if you intend to use UDP, you either need to make really sure to never exceed the minimum guaranteed packet size for your network, or use some mechanism to reassemble larger messages from individual packets.

Is there a specific reason for using UDP here? It seems TCP (or an even higher level protocol) would have been a more convenient choice.

Did you copy copy code as is or edit it before ask question? Line 'IPAddress.Parse("ipAddress"), port)' has to use argument 'ipAddress' without quotes. In current state it raises: 'An invalid IP address was specified.'

Sorry for the late answer guys , the udp never exceeds more than 1 package of 65000 bytes, its less so im ok with that i could use also tcp but i dont care for packet loss or assemble ,the thing is that im not sure if i dispose correctly or if the port for some reason stays open...i think its something about my port to be honest.

Sorry yes i must edit the ipAddress with quotes.My bad, its not the bug this for sure,i just edit it for some reason last second .
